# Animating pyplot subplots

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I have read widely on this topic and spent several hours looking for ways to implement an animation for my plot.

I have managed an "animation" in-loop using `plt.ion()`, however, I can't get anything in `matplotlib.animation` to produce me an animated clip.

Below is a basic setup of the data I have to animate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class plot_output(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(2,10)
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()
    def iterate_animation(self, i, weight_list):
        X = weight_list[i]
        for i in range(20):
            self.ax[i/10, i%10].cla()
            wi = X[:,i]
            wi=wi.reshape((28,28))
            self.ax[i/10, i%10].axis('off')
            self.ax[i/10, i%10].imshow(wi,cmap=plt.cm.gist_yarg,
                interpolation='gaussian', aspect='equal')
        plt.draw()

w_list = [np.random.rand(784,20) for i in range(4)]
p = plot_output()

for i in range(4):
    p.iterate_animation(i=i, weight_list=w_list)
```